# Excel Parameters in Query - Invalid parameter number

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a Microsoft SQL Query in my Excel sheet. When I hardcode the dates it works just fine. However if I try to change the dates to `?` and use parameters I get an error `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number` followed by `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index`.

The part of the query in question is:

```
AND (spa.sba_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

What's weird is if I click on the `Parameters...` button it only lists one parameter:

[image: parameter screen]

`Info!$B$9` is a cell with the formula `=DATE(B3,B2,B1)` (B1-B3 are cells with a number in them).

Here is the entire query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT sba_date,
        MIN(provider_start_time) AS 'provider_start_time',
        MAX(provider_end_time) AS 'provider_end_time',
        provider_code
    FROM book
    GROUP BY sba_date, provider_code
)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.sba_date, 101) AS '<DATEIN>',
    FORMAT(CAST(c.provider_start_time AS DATETIME), 'h:mm tt') AS '<TIMEIN>',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.sba_date, 101) AS '<DATEOUT>',
    FORMAT(CAST(c.provider_end_time AS DATETIME), 'h:mm tt') AS '<TIMEOUT>',
    (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.provider_start_time, c.provider_end_time)) AS '<MINHOURS>',
    (spa.service_detail + ' in the ' + spa.room_code) AS '<SHIFTDESC>',
    client.last_name
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN client client ON c.provider_code = client.client_code
INNER JOIN book spa ON spa.sba_date = c.sba_date
    AND spa.provider_code = c.provider_code
    AND spa.provider_start_time = c.provider_start_time
WHERE spa.status = 'cf'
    AND (spa.sba_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
ORDER BY c.sba_date, last_name, spa.provider_start_time
```

Comment: Side note: when specifying an alias, it's redundent to use an alias that is the same as the object. `INNER JOIN client client ON ...` could simply be `INNER JOIN client ON...`.

Comment: Another slight detour...you are using between with date time values. This can be very problematic. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common Also, you are using string literals as column aliases. This is not just confusing, it has been deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15 Not really sure why you want your columns wrapped like html/xml tags anyway.

Comment: @Larnu the actual table name is something different, just wanted to hide the true name.

@SeanLange if I'm reading that first article right I think I'm fine. All the `sba_date`'s are stored with no time (eg `2019-01-01 00:00:00.000`). I will look at the second link though.

Comment: @SeanLange unfortunately `{expression} AS 'String Literal'` is **not** deprecated, it's only `'String Literal' = {expression}`. The document linked even has `expression [AS] 'column_alias'` as a suggested replacement for `'string_alias' = expression`.

Comment: @Larnu...sadly you are correct. It really should be deprecated because it is just awful. I know I am not alone in that...but I guess it is valid.

Comment: I completely agree that it *should* be as well, @SeanLange .

Comment: Change the BETWEEN to >= and < and possibly move the parenthesis around and see if you get the prompt for your 2nd param.

Comment: @JacobH I tried `AND (spa.sba_date >= ?) AND (spa.sba_date < ?)`, `AND (spa.sba_date >= ? AND spa.sba_date < ?)`, & `AND spa.sba_date >= ? AND spa.sba_date < ?`; none worked.

Comment: Hi @WolfieeifloW, did you resolve the problem please? What have you done to make **Parameter2** to appear? I'm failing on this as well?